# What does QM observable operator actually DO?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I know, that each observable is represented by some linear operator, while it's eigenvalues represent probability amplitudes of possible observable values.

But what if I ACT with this operator on some state. Will this action have some physical sense?

Comment: Comment on question (v1): the eigenvalues of the operator do *not* represent probability amplitudes, they represent the possible values one can obtain when making a measurement of the corresponding physical quantity.

Comment: Forgive me, for my QM is very rusty. If you act with a measurement device represented by such an operator on the quantum system (mathematical operators don't act on physical systems or states thereof, only experimental devices do), the quantum system will be in the state described by the measured eigenvalue of the operator after the measurement. Basically, a measurement and the preparation of a state are one and the same thing... at least in a very naive interpretation of QM. Someone who knows better please correct me, because I may have told you complete nonsense.